# Why application is hanging when it tries to send some data using SSL_write?

Tags: c++, openssl

I need to transfer data using OpenSSL. But some data is not transferring.
There are two files with data.
`dt1` works good. But my application is hanging when it tries to send `dt2`.

[dt1](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14876829258265568392)
[dt2](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=77386316202535621345)

```
// SERVER
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>

int OpenListener(int port)
{
    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        perror("can't bind port");
        abort();
    }
    if (listen(sd, 10) != 0) {
        perror("Can't configure listening port");
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

SSL_CTX* InitServerCTX(void)
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    method = SSLv2_server_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

void LoadCertificates(SSL_CTX* ctx, char* CertFile, char* KeyFile)
{
    if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, CertFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KeyFile, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    if (!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ctx)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Private key does not match the public certificate\n");
        abort();
    }
}

int main()
{
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    SSL_library_init();

    ctx = InitServerCTX();
    LoadCertificates(ctx, "sert.crt", "sert.key");
    server = OpenListener(7654);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);

    int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);

    SSL *ssl;
    printf("Connection: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), ntohs(addr.sin_port));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);

    if (SSL_accept(ssl) == -1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    else {
        std::ifstream fin("dt1", std::ios::binary);
        std::string data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin)),
                                        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        fin.close();

        //////////////////////////////////////////////
        SSL_write(ssl, &data[0], (int)data.size()); // dt1- good. data2 - hanging
        //////////////////////////////////////////////

        const int BUF_SIZE = 0x100000;
        std::string data1;
        data1.resize(BUF_SIZE);
        int n = SSL_read(ssl, &data1[0], BUF_SIZE);

        if (n >= 0) {
            data1.resize(n);
        }

        bool b = (data == data1);
    }

    SSL_free(ssl);
    closesocket(client);
}
```

-

```
// CLIENT
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#define _WINSOCKAPI_
#include <windows.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>

SSL_CTX *InitCTX(void)
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    method = SSLv2_client_method();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        abort();
    }
    return ctx;
}

int OpenConnection(const char *hostName, int port)
{
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    if ((host = gethostbyname(hostName)) == NULL) {
        perror(hostName);
        abort();
    }
    int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
    if (connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        closesocket(sd);
        perror(hostName);
        abort();
    }
    return sd;
}

int main()
{
    const std::string &hostName = "localhost";
    const int port = 7654;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    SSL_library_init();

    SSL_CTX *ctx = InitCTX();
    int server = OpenConnection(hostName.c_str(), port);
    SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);
    if (SSL_connect(ssl) == -1) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    else {
        const int BUF_SIZE = 0x100000;
        std::string data;
        data.resize(BUF_SIZE);
        int n = SSL_read(ssl, &data[0], BUF_SIZE);
        data.resize(n);

        SSL_write(ssl, &data[0], (int)data.size());

        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hanging means client is not able to call `SSL_read` or is not there. Check if client has reached to `SSL_read` when server wants to call `SSL_write`.

Comment: @doptimusprime Client has reached to SSL_read and accepted data. But SSL_write on server is hanging.

Comment: Then make sure that client should all the data. Although I think it would silly to assume that server is getting blocked while sending the data as its buffers are occupied. Check that how much bytes you are sending must be received by the client.

Comment: @doptimusprime dt2 size is 71820. Client SSL_read received 32744.

Comment: Since your socket is blocking, if send of all the data is not complete, it will block. Try to send the data in parts (say multiple of 1kB rather than at once.)